# Bootstrap, Custom buttons and selection box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-canvas

How do I design buttons and selection box shown in this image. I am using bootstrap 3.

I am new to html5 and bootstrap.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ehyu6a&s=8#.VYuoR_mqqko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the basic CSS? If that is the case the CSS for something like that looks something like:

```
.your-button {
  border: #999 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

To start off with...

Use this tool to add a gradient.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Okay, That worked.. thank you :).  I modified it a little bit and now it's looking fine. But button when pressed, only the border is highlighted and it doesn't look like it is pressed. Like in the image.